# New Page is open when I click on gallery view

Tags: jquery, android, phonegap-plugins

I have display images from sdcard in grid view using PhotoSwipe of Jquery. Now I want to click on images and new page is open for displaying images individually.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the image link, add the attribute

> target

```
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/images/thisimage.jpg" target="_blank">Click here to view image</a>
```

Comment: My images came from sd card dynamically.